# Downgrade NodeJs Version and express version

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I am working on a nodejs project. I have installed Express 3.X which is in alpha stage, and my node version is also at 0.7.2-pre. I am currently trying to downgrade my express version, via npm, but it seems that i have to downgrade my node version as well.

What is the best way to achieve this? How do i down grade my node version. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To easy the node version management you can use an npm package called [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n)

Comment: That package does not work with Windows as all node components should because it relies on Bash.

Answer (score 3):

There are tools that allow you to have multiple versions of Node installed - e.g. [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - so you could do that.

However, to answer the question, you will need to re-install Node I'm afraid. Thankfully installing from source is pretty easy though a little slow. Just follow the installation instructions on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/joyent/node).